# Passing parameters to python -c inside a bash function?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, django

I need to print the value of a Django setting while in a Bash shell.

Basically, the command I'd like to run is `python -c 'from django.conf import settings; print settings.MEDIA_ROOT'`. I need to be in a certain path and pass `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to it though, so I thought I'd wrap the whole thing inside a bash function that I could call instead, `pyt -c [...]`

I've used `$@` successfully in the past in similar situations, so I was hoping it would help here, too. But it's not working as I've got it set up right now.

```
function pyt {
    cd $PROJECT_ROOT # set elsewhere, parent dir of my_site
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_site.settings python $@
    cd $OLDPWD
}
```

If I type `pyt -c "print 'foo'"` to test it, "foo" is not printed. A blank line is. `python -c "print 'foo'"` prints it correctly, so it's something to do with my function here.

If I put `echo $@` inside the function, all the parameters are printed out just fine. The Python interpreter is not started either (it is if I just type `pyt`), so the -c parameter seems to be having *some* effect—nothing just gets printed out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the arguments get passed around.

When you run `python -c "print 'foo'"` the shell parses it into

- `python`
- `-c`
- `print 'foo'`

so python ends up seeing two arguments.

When you run `pyt -c "print 'foo'"` the line `python $@` gets expanded to (the equivalent of) `python -c print 'foo'`, which gets tokenised as

- `python`
- `-c`
- `print`
- `foo`

i.e. python sees three arguments, and will run the command `print`, with the string `foo` in `sys.argv[1]`.

What you need to do is use a magic shell token: instead of just `$@` use `"$@"` (it must be double quotes). That tells the shell to keep arguments together; when you run `pyt -c "print 'foo'"`, the line `python "$@"` gets expanded to (the equivalent of) `python -c "print 'foo'"`.